# ¿Cómo creo un Build Definition de un proyecto ASP.NET WebForms con referencias a DevExpress?

Tags: asp.net, git, visual-studio-2015, devexpress, visual-studio-ts

Hola gente necesito saber como puedo crear una definición de compilación para un proyecto de ASP.NET WebForms, he seguido los pasos para los proyectos MVC pero creo que no funcionan con los WebForms.

La URL de la cual me basé fue de [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/azure/aspnet4)

Actualmente mi proyecto Web tiene referencias a DevExpress y otras dependencias locales y estas dependencias no provienen de Nuget.

Uso Git como control de versiones en el Team Services.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola Erick Orlando, he modificado mi respuesta incluyendo algunos detalles de lo que usé para una demo que hice en el [ReConnect 2015 de DotNetters](http://dotnetters.es/connect-and-reconnect/). Espero que, por lo menos, te sirva para poder avanzar. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [artículo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/azure/aspnet4) en la que te has basado para crear la definición de compilación es el correcto pero no solo es para compilar la aplicación sino que también la publica como sitio web de Azure.

El proceso de compilación y publicación de las aplicaciones ASP.NET WebForms es el mismo que el de las aplicaciones ASP.NET MVC por lo que te debería funcionar.

El problema que estás teniendo es que en el servidor de build no están los ensamblados de DevExpress y los otros ensamblados locales que comentas.

La mejor solución para esto es generar los paquetes Nuget de tus dependencias (se hace con la utilidad Nuget.exe) y publicarlos usando el [nuevo servicio de gestión de paquetes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/package/overview) que incorpora el propio Visual Studio Team Services y que está integrado con el sistema de Build.

En la siguiente imagen puedes ver como queda una definición de build de este tipo:

[image: Definición de build]

Como puedes ver en la imagen, se usa un archivo Nuget.Config (que está junto con el código fuente) donde se establece la configuración que usará el sistema de build para restaurar los paquetes Nuget.

Este es el contenido de dicho archivo que usé para hacer una demo con motivo del [Re-Connect 2005 de DotNetters](http://dotnetters.es/connect-and-reconnect/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
</packageRestore>
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="api.nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="ReConnect2015b" value="https://dotnetters.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_packaging/ReConnect2015/nuget/v3/index.json" />
</packageSources>
<disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="api.nuget.org" value="true" />
</disabledPackageSources>
<activePackageSource>
</activePackageSource>
<packageSourceCredentials>
    <ReConnect2015b>
    <add key="Username" value="**falta el nombre de usuario**" />
    <add key="Password" value="**falta el HASH de la contraseña**" />
    </ReConnect2015b>
</packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

- El feed de Team Services está nombrado como ReConnect2015b
- El acceso a este feed está protegido por lo que es necesario proporcionar el usuario y contraseña, la generación de estas credenciales está explicado [aquí](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/package/nuget/auth)

Los pasos para tener tun dependencias como paquetes Nuget son los siguientes *(hay enlaces a la documentación pero están en inglés)*:

1. [Crear un nuevo feed de paquetes en TFS Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/package/feeds/create-feed)
2. [Generar los paquetes Nuget correspondientes a los ensamblados de DevExpress y los otros ensamblados locales](http://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#from-an-assembly)
3. [Publicar los paquetes en el feed](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/package/nuget/publish)
4. [Configurar Visual Studio para usar el feed de paquetes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/package/nuget/consume) y replazar las referencias de tu proyecto para que usen estos paquetes
5. [Configurar el primer paso de la definición de compilación](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/package/build/team-build) para que, al restaurar los paquetes Nuget use el feed donde están los paquetes

Y así es como se ve un feed de paquetes Nuges en Visual Studio Team Services

[image: Nuget Feed]

Comment: Perfecto! esta era la solución que andaba buscando, muchísimas gracias :D

Comment: De nada @ErickOrlando, me alegro que te haya servido